# Proof that a root of $x^3+4x=6$ is between 1.1 and 1.2

Tags: proof-writing, factoring, cubics

I have this math problem that I have to solve (Edexcel GCSE 9-1 Mathematics Higher Student Book) which says:

Show that the equation $$x^3+4x=6$$ has a solution between 1.1 and 1.2.

The lesson is on expanding and factorizing, and all these problems are quadratic except this one. I have asked my teacher for a hint and all she says is "look at the problem from a different angle".

How can I prove it (obviously not using the calculator equation solving mode)?

Comment: You could use Intermediate Value Theorem for this, I don't know if you're familiar with it.

Comment: If $f(x)=x^3+4x-6$ then $f(1.1)<0$ and $f(1.2)>0$.  Not sure what else you can say here...

Comment: @lulu you should make that an answer.

Comment: @Chinny84  Oh...it's equivalent to the "Intermediate Value Theorem" solution/comment/hint posted below .  And it is certainly not clear that this is the solution the OP is looking for.

Comment: it is up to you - but at least from my time doing the GCSE program I did not use the term " Intermediate Value Theorem" but to be fair it is up to the OP and not me.

Comment: @Chinny84 my teacher might not be very happy that I used something not in the GCSE program to solve it. It was a GCSE book so I'm pretty sure it can be solved with GCSE level math(s).

Comment: @YubinLee Sorry, to ask: do you know to calculate derivatives?

Comment: @JimmyR. To an extent. I do know the power rule but GCSE maths assumes I don't.

Comment: @YubinLee look at Lulus comment.

Comment: @Chinny84 What would be a solution assuming I knew derivation?

Comment: Since it's a monotone function, can't you just plug those two bounds into the equation and show that since one is less than 6 and the other is greater than 6, the answer must lie in between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough to apply the intermediate value theorem to the continuous function $p(x)=x(x^2+4)$.
We have
$p\left(\frac{11}{10}\right) = \frac{11}{10}\cdot \frac{521}{100}<6 $ and $p\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)=\frac{6}{5}\cdot\frac{136}{25}>6$, hence $p(x)$ takes for sure the value $6$ over the interval $I=(1.1,1.2)$. Since $p(x)$ is a convex function over such interval (due to $p''(x)>0$) the sequence of approximations provided by
$$ x_0=\frac{6}{5},\qquad x_{n+1}=2\cdot\frac{3+x^3}{4+3x^2} $$
is quadratically and monotonically convergent to an actual zero of $p(x)-6$ over $I$, by the properties of [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). If we consider $x_1=\frac{591}{520}$, we already have 
$$ p(x_1)-6<\frac{1}{70}.$$
We may also find an explicit solution. Since $p(x)$ is an increasing function (due to $p'(x)>0$),
 the only real zero of $p(x)-6$ is given by

$$ \xi = \alpha+\frac{4}{3\alpha},\qquad \alpha=\sqrt[3]{3+\tfrac{1}{9}\sqrt{921}} $$
by the [cubic formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html), where $\xi\approx 1.1347284533618458$.